# could anyone tell me how to write this simple algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

could anyone tell me how to write this simple algorithm? Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the layout of package `algorithm2e`.   Take a look at its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This was done with the `algorithm2e` package. It's simply a case of working out the package options required and defining a couple of key words.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled, noend, noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKw{KwInitialisation}{Initialisation:}
        \SetKw{KwReturn}{return}
        \KwInitialisation \(X_0 \sim \mu\), \((\xi_k)\) i.i.d., \(X_0 \upmodels (\xi_k)\)
        
        \For{\(k = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc\)}{
            \(X_{k+1} = T_{\xi_k} X_k\)
        }
        \KwReturn{\(\{X_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\)}
        \caption{Random Function Iteration (RFI)}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just use the predefined `\Return`.