# Could anyone tell me how to write this in an algorithm format in latex?

Tags: algorithms

Could anyone tell me how to write this in an algorithm format in latex? p-37,38. Thank you.

https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/11017/Maki_Erik.pdf?sequence=3&isAllowed=y

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

This was done using the `enumerate` environment and the `amsmath` package for the `\dotsc` command. I also included a label and reference although for something this small you could do the number manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Select \(x_0 \in X\)
        \item Calculate \(\mathbf{p}(x_0) = (p_1(x_0), p_2(x_0), \dotsc, p_N(x_0))\)
        \item Select \(w_{\sigma_1} \in \{1, \dotsc, N\}\) 
        according to the probabilities, \(\mathbf{p}(x_0)\)
        \item \label{step 4} Apply \(w_{\sigma_1}\), \(x_1 = w_{\sigma_1}(x_0)\)
        \item Repeat this process using \(x_n = w_{\sigma_n}(x_{n-1})\)
        (calculated in Step \ref{step 4}) as the new \(x_0\).
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

This can also be done using the `algorithm` environment of the `algorithm2e` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SetNlSty{}{}{.}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \nl Select \(x_0 \in X\)
        
        \nl Calculate \(\mathbf{p}(x_0) = (p_1(x_0), p_2(x_0), \dotsc, p_N(x_0))\)
        
        \nl Select \(w_{\sigma_1} \in \{1, \dotsc, N\}\) 
        according to the probabilities, \(\mathbf{p}(x_0)\)
        
        \nl Apply \(w_{\sigma_1}\), \(x_1 = w_{\sigma_1}(x_0)\)
        
        \nl Repeat this process using \(x_n = w_{\sigma_n}(x_{n-1})\)
        (calculated in Step 4) as the new \(x_0\).
        \caption{An Algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which produces
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping inside \begin{algorithm} \end{algorithm} for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605538/could-anyone-tell-me-how-to-write-this-simple-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment1518375_605538